# Caption of figure not centred

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, ieeetran

I'm using the template provided by IEEE:

```
\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth]{top}
\caption{CAPTION}
\label{fig-top}
\end{figure}
```

However the caption is not centred. What I get is this:

[image]

Please help!

Comment: The figure is centered... your image is the one that perhaps has a lot of white space either right or left.  Just open it with any image editor and crop the parts you don't want.  The caption should be justified, as required by the `IEEEtran` style.  Also, please note that `IEEEtran`  requires the width to be `2.5in`, not `0.8\columnwidth` (although I think it's pretty much the same).

Comment: @MarioS.E. I double checked the figure, it is cropped properly. I've used several different figures and all have the same problem. Thanks for the 2.5in error.

Comment: The format of [`IEEEtran`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran) is to set the caption in full-width (left justified) when you don't use any class options.

Comment: ...I must insist with the fact that `IEEEtran` is set properly.  If you want to comply with this style you **must not** change the way the caption is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the easiest way to fix this, as suggested in [a related StackExchange Post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100434/centering-figure-captions-in-ieeetran), is to add `\usepackage{caption}` into your preamble. This centers the caption relative to the figure.

However, in doing this you're changing a few aspects of the `IEEEtran` formatting, which might be a problem depending on what you use this document for (e.g. for a journal, you probably want to stick with their style).